# how to provide printing feature in Android application

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to provide printing feature in android application ,suppose i have read reference application if i want to print some topic so how to implement this thing

in this feature WiFi and Bluetooth printer are required

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have a server application running on your desktop computer with a printer attached. Your Android device must run a client application, that will send the data to the server for printing. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlokTiwari, Nope, don't have any code for such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/?hl=en

you an also use cloud printer type architecture